# Correct usage of the word "do" in this context

Tags: verbs, tenses

I have the following sentence:

"In other words, Rule 5 has a balancing test and the limiting factors, which restrict admissibility the same way that 6(a) & 6(b) *do*."

In this case, what should be the correct usage of the word "do"?

Comment: This the correct use. Use _do_ if you use _that_. If you use _as_ instead, don't use _do_.

Comment: Right. I guess I'm confused as to whether it should be "do" or "does". Can you explain the verb tense usage?

Comment: It should be do. The coordination of 6(a) & 6(b) means that the subject's plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*DO* here is the dummy auxiliary verb. It is being used to stand in for *restrict admissibility*. *Do* here means *do restrict admissibility*. A technical term for this is that *DO* is being used to *take code*. There is no other auxiliary verb here which can take code, so the dummy auxiliary is being used. If we had a modal verb or other auxiliary, we could have used that instead. Compare:

- which restrict admissibility the same way that (6a) & (6b) do.
- which can restrict admissibility the same way that (6a) & (6b) can.
- which have restricted admissibility the same way that (6a) & (6b) have.

The subject of this verb is the coordinated Noun Phase *(6a) & (6b)*. Although the (6b) on its own would be singular, because there are two entities in the Subject, *DO* is agreeing with the plural subject. This is entirely correct.

*Hope this is helpful!*